# getting data from events

Tags: web3js, web3.py, python, solidity-0.6.x

versions:
solidity 6.0.0
python3.8
web3 5.13.1

I am trying to get return data from a smart contract function that changes a struct  on the contract. I cannot do that using return because the transaction changes the blockchain, so I read that I can use a Solidity event. Now running my code I am getting the following error:

```
 web3.exceptions.SolidityError: execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Request not approved yet.
```

Below is some of the contract. The `getKYCData` is what is giving me the problem.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract ReturnData
    

    struct KYCData {
        string name;
        string home;
        string tin;
        string phone;
    }

    event WalletData(
        string name,
        string home,
        string tin,
        string phone
    );

    Request[] public requests;
    uint[] public request_ids;
    address public manager;
    address public owner;
    KYCData private data;
    uint public serviceCost;

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager || msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    constructor (address wallet_owner, address admin, string memory name, string memory home,
        string memory tin, string memory phone, uint serviceFee) public {
        manager = admin;
        owner = wallet_owner;
        data = KYCData({
            name: name,
            home:home,
            tin: tin,
            phone: phone
        });
        serviceCost = serviceFee;
    }

    function getData() public restricted view returns (string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory) {
        return (data.name, data.home, data.tin, data.phone);
    }

    function makeRequest(string memory name, string memory description) public payable returns (uint) {
        require(msg.value > serviceCost, "Did not meet fee requirement.");

        Request memory newRequest = Request({
            requestor: msg.sender,
            name: name,
            description: description,
            approved: false,
            active: true
        });
        requests.push(newRequest);
        uint val = request_ids.length;
        request_ids.push(val + 1);
        return val;
    }

    function approveRequest(uint index) public restricted {
        Request storage request = requests[index-1];

        request.approved = true;
    }

    function getKYCData(uint index) public returns (string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory) {
        Request storage request = requests[index-1];

        require(request.approved, "Request not approved yet.");
        require(request.active, "Request is not active");
        require(msg.sender == request.requestor, "Must be requested from request originator.");

        request.active = false;
        emit WalletData(data.name, data.home, data.tin, data.phone);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Using events to get return values from functions is not the same as using `return` in view/pure functions. In fact you shouldn't use the keyword `returns` when declaring a function that results in a transaction. The only exception to this is if you call such a function inside of another function in the smart contract:

```
 uint256 public x = 0;
 
 function first() internal  pure returns(uint256){
     return 10;
 }
 
 function second() public {
     x = put();
 }
```

When emitting an event in solidity the parameters passed to it are stored in the Logs, a special data structure found inside each transaction receipt. Keep in mind that there is extra cost for emitting an event as it is considered a [state modifying action](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/contracts.html#view-functions)

Anyway, in your case, changing
`function getKYCData(uint index) public returns (string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory)`

to `function getKYCData(uint index) public` should do the work.

Then you can use web3 to listen for new events/Logs and retrieve the data you want when the transaction is completed and its receipt is available. Unfortunately i don't think there is a more efficient way to do it, i.e not waiting for the transaction to complete.

web3.js example for listening for a new event:

```
//create instance of contract
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI_of_contract, address_of_contract);

//listen for new events
contract.events.WalletData({
  fromBlock: 'latest'
  }, function(error, event){
      console.log(event); 
  });
```

Also, you can consult an [example](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id50) from web3 docs for better understanding.

Other than using events to return values from functions, you may treat them as a cheaper way of storage. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65411577/14861243) or a nice post from ConsenSys [here](https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e)

I hope this will be of help!